# Is there any way to get only parent terms from custom taxonomy or category?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

Is there any way to get only parent terms from custom taxonomy or category?

```
 $genres = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'genres', '<div class="genres"><div class="mta">', '', '</div></div>');
```

Comment: Please view this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24582/how-can-i-get-only-parent-terms

Answer (score 2):

You can build the list alone without childrens.

```
/**
 * @param post_id can use 'get_the_ID()'
 * @param taxonomy for example 'category'
 */
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, $taxonomy, array('parent'=>'0'));
foreach($terms as $term) {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a> 
    <?php
}
```

The second option is that you can filter the terms and remove all the terms with parent bigger than 0 for the `get_the_term_list()` function.

```
function remove_child_terms($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy) {
    /**
     * Add some condition here to limit this for your custom taxonomy
     * if($taxonomy == 'something') {
     */
    foreach($terms as $key => $term) {
        if($term->parent !== 0) {
            unset($terms[$key]);
        }
    }
    /**
     * }
     */
    return $terms;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'remove_child_terms', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: If you use the first code you need to replace the `$taxonomy` with your taxonomy.. if you use the second code you should place it inside functions.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
 <?php $terms = get_terms( array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name',
        'parent'   => 0
    ) );
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } ?>
```

Comment: Passing in a `parent` parameter with value of `0` will give you hierarchical taxonomies without a parent.

Comment: As you can see he pass the `$post->ID` and he use `get_the_term_list()` so he want the terms that associated with the post...